# Animate at re-selected index not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-plot

I implemented `corePlot` in my `xcode` project using the pie chart. I'm having trouble the animation. When a slice gets selected, the radial offset changes with animation. Here is the code:

```
- (void)pieChart:(CPTPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    if (self.selectedIndex == idx)
    {
        [self animateSelectedIndex:20 :0];
        self.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectedIndex = idx;
        [self animateSelectedIndex:0 :20];
    }
}

- (void)animateSelectedIndex:(CGFloat)from :(CGFloat)to
{
    [CPTAnimation animate:self
                 property:@"sliceOffset"
                     from:from
                       to:to
                 duration:0.25
           animationCurve:CPTAnimationCurveCubicInOut
                 delegate:nil];
}

- (CGFloat)radialOffsetForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    return  idx == self.selectedIndex ? sliceOffset : 0.0;
}

- (void)setSliceOffset:(CGFloat)newOffset
{
    if (newOffset != sliceOffset) {
        sliceOffset = newOffset;
        [self.graph reloadData];
    }
}
```

The problem is, when a slice gets **re-selected**, the slice's radial offset goes to 0, but it doesn't animate to 0. (When it goes from 0 to 20 it does animate. The only problem is when it goes from 20 to 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the `selectedIndex` drives the radial offset to zero right away. Don't clear it until after the animation finishes. You can use an animation delegate or clear it in `-setSliceOffset:` after the offset reaches zero.